# Event still inactive even if it is part of a workflow in Jira Data Server

Tags: groovy, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I would like an event to be fired when a transition is executed.

[image]

Here is the whole picture

[image]

The transition is still shown as inactive even though it is used by a workflow. The draft has already been published, it is not a draft. 
[image]

How can I fix this problem and make the transition valid?

The event is also not fired when I click on the transition
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of versions ago, there was a minor bug in Jira that meant you also have to have triggered the event at least once to get Jira to realise that the event is active.  I do not know if that has been fixed, but a good test remains behind it - try triggering the event and then going back to look at its state.